# Centering objects in grid with Foundation 4

Tags: grid, center, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to create a grid of categories for this site: http://oranjsushi.com/test/menu.html
Problem is, I can't get the boxes to center after the breakpoint. 
Any ideas?

Comment: I need to find a way to make the ul holding the boxes to adjust it size according to the boxes inside. As for now, the ul simply stretches to fill his parent div. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Problem solved! I removed the float from the boxes, and gave them "inline-block".